# Remove CSS with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a style tag in my project, which is generated automatically. I want to remove some of the styles of this tag that interfere with other classes

this is my CSS and style tag:

```
<style id="style-inline-inline-css">

#et-boc .et-l div {
    text-align: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: inherit;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    text-shadow: inherit;
    border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    transition: none;
}

#et-boc .et-l img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
</style>
```

I want to remove this two CSS `#et-boc .et-l img` and `#et-boc .et-l div` with JavaScript or jQuery and other ways, Due to the structure of the project and the automatic generation of the codes, I cannot delete them on the back-end side. The only way in the front-end is to prevent them from being applied to the site elements

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what research you've done and any attempts you've made based on that research.

Comment: You could just give them another css class with a more specific selector and override these styles. It's definitely possible to iterate over css rules and delete them, but seems kind of odd

Comment: As @CollinD suggested, it's best to create another class that overrides specific styles needed to correct the page.  Removing or altering existing classes can often have unforeseen side effects on other parts of the page. Use browser dev tools to live edit the css to quickly see what works best.

Comment: You could create a CSS style which has [more specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), like `body #et-boc .et-l img` (because "body" will exist but this styling is more specific), and override the styles that way. In case you don't want to introduce extra classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this would be the best approach for your exact goal. Anyway, I took the chance to craft a demo that shows how to access the stylesheets from JavaScript and how to remove a specific CSS rule.

For reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/cssRules
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule

This demo shows how a CSS rule can be found and deleted from a given style element (fetched by ID) using its selector as a key:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
  const styleElement = document.getElementById('style-inline-inline-css');
  const stylesheet = styleElement.sheet;  
  removeCssRuleMatchingSelector(stylesheet, '#et-boc .et-l div');  
});

function removeCssRuleMatchingSelector(stylesheet, selector){
  const cssRules = stylesheet.cssRules;    
  let foundRule = null;
  let foundRuleIndex = -1;
  for(let i=0; i<cssRules.length; i++){
    if (cssRules[i].selectorText == selector){
      foundRule = cssRules[i];
      foundRuleIndex = i;
      break;
    }      
  }
  if (foundRule !== null){
    stylesheet.deleteRule( foundRuleIndex );    
  }    
}
```

```html
<style id="style-inline-inline-css">
  
  /*css rule to delete*/
  #et-boc .et-l div {
      background: green;
  }
  
  /*css rule to remain unchanged*/
  .test{
    background: red;
  }
</style>

<div id="et-boc">
  <div class="et-l">
    <div>If the rule was not deleted, this paragraph would be styled with bg green</div>  
  </div>
</div>

<div class="test">TEST</div>
```

Comment: this not work because my css selector in tag style , format is : `#et-boc .et-l a:active, #et-boc .et-l blockquote, #et-boc .et-l div, #et-boc .et-l em, #et-boc .et-l form, #et-boc` must find only `#et-boc .et-l div` in this multi selector and delete it, thanks